# постфиксный и префиксный ++

Tags: c++

```
for (int i=0;i<100;++i) ;
for (int i=0;i<100;i++) ;
```

Есть ли разница, как писать, ведь постфиксный `++` сложнее реализовывается?

Comment: откуда подозрение что сложнее реализован постфиксный?

Comment: Ну там же временная копия создается

Comment: @bulebyaka там будет inc eax в любом случае.

Answer (score 4):

Пока вы работаете со встроенными типами типа `int` - разницы никакой. Компиляторы достаточно умные.

При пользовательских типах может быть все, что угодно - имею в виду, нарушение семантики. Может, кому-то в голову взбредет в префиксном файлы записывать, а в постфиксном - стирать :) При соблюдении семантики, понятно, постфиксный реализуется сложнее.

Поэтому и рекомендуется приучать себя писать `++i` - просто чтоб выработать привычку :)

Answer (score 3):

> В вызывающем коде лучше использовать префиксные операторы, если только вам не требуется исходное значение, возвращаемое постфиксной версией. Префиксная форма семантически эквивалентна, она вводится практически так же, и зачастую немного эффективнее, так как создает на один объект меньше. Это не преждевременная оптимизация, а устранение преждевременной пессимизации.

[Саттер, Александреску. Стандарты программирования на C++.](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0859-0.html)

Answer (score 2):

Результат третьего выражения в `for` всегда игнорируется, важен только **побочный эффект** от его выполнения. А значит, весь код, относящийся **только** к генерации его возвращаемого значения и возврату оного (если в этом контексте "возврат" вообще имеет смысл), может быть безопасно выкинут.

Для `int i; for (int i=0;i<100;i++) ;`, путём **[удаления мёртвого кода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) (записи значения, которое далее не используется)** компилятор может убрать из `i++` весь несущественный код, относящийся к возвращаемому значению этого выражения, оставив только побочный эффект. И получится код, **эквивалентный `++i`**.

Важно то, что **компилятор здесь не заменяет постфиксный вариант на префиксный**, а **убирает лишний код** из постфиксного, который **"по чистой случайности"** для `int` оказывается эквивалентен своему префиксному "братцу". Для других типов эквивалентный код может запросто оказаться другим.

...если ваш компилятор вообще достаточно умён, чтобы так делать. Скорее всего — достаточно. [Вот пример в compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A[%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22G4ewlgJgBAxgnjANgUwIwAoCUUDeAoKKAMxACcp0wA7AFyjAF4AGAbjAB5UnWBqHsbCzwBfPKEiwEKAExZcBYmQrU6jVhy7q%2BgkUAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g447%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22%22%7D]%7D) (на самой старой версии компилятора, что я там нашёл), и он даёт одинаковый результат. Попереключайте компилятор, сравните, одинаков ли код.